# JavaFX application - Could not create the Java Virtual Machine, fatal exception

Tags: java, javafx, jvm

I've created a JavaFX Application in IntelliJ for the first time.
To that end, I've imported the JavaFX libraries into my project libraries and built a jar from my project. Then I've used Launch4j to wrap it as an executable file with following JVM options:

```
--module-path /Users/myName/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

On the PC I've created the application it obviously runs smoothly. If I want to use it on another computer, I run into the following exception when I try to launch it:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My question is if the application can't be launched due to the path I've given in the JVM options (since this seems very 'local' you could say, I guess) and it tries to add modules from a place that doesn't exist on my other PC?
If so, how can I fix it so the exe can be launched on any PC without issues, as in so I don't have to download the lib on any PC. So where should I place the lib of the SDK? Is there any default way to do this, or what's the cleanest way?

And if I'm completely wrong... What else am I missing? Is it a memory problem?

Apologies if this is a dumb question and thanks in advance!

Comment: I havent used IntelliJ, but i guess it works the same as eclipse.
`--module-path /Users/myName/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
`
is your run configuration, if you export a jar, this will not be considered.
My advice is to convert your project to a maven project and add the JavaFX dependencies

Comment: I did that now :) And it does work! I used gradle before all that but for some reason it refused to work and since I had never used maven before I thought I might try adding the libraries manually and go from there... Considering that JavaFX was already causing problems. Now I regret going the long way of avoiding maven. Adding all dependencies via maven and then using a plugin to export a jar worked wonders.

Comment: glad to hear :3 however, what plugin are you using to export the jar?

Comment: I'm using the maven assembly plugin that I read about from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: I never used an assembly plugin, I just include everything needed in the build path and simply export the jar, and it works

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an IntelliJ thing where you need the plugin... I think I did read somewhere that Eclipse is easier in some ways when it comes to exporting a jar. Worth reading up more on the whole building artifacts/maven and all, I suppose.